# I can't acquire JSON data AngularJS

Tags: json, angularjs, api

I want to get THE MOVIE REVIEWS API by The New York Times. I tried it using AngularJS but I was not provided.Can someone help me?

```
var app = angular.module('movieApp', []);
app.controller('movieController',
    function movieController($scope, $http) {
        $scope.fetchReviews = function() {
            var api = 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/all.jsonp?&offset=20&order=by-opening-date&api-key=XXX MY KEY XXX&responce-format=.jsonp&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'; 
            $http.jsonp(api).success(function(data){
                $scope.results = data.results;
            });
        }

    });
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="movieApp">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Movie Review</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="movieController">
    <ul class="review-cards">
        <li ng-repeat="item in results">
            <h2>{{item.display_title}}</h2>
            <p>{{item.summary_short}}</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when the fetchReviews function get fired

Comment: Right, you need to call the fetchReviews function. In the code you posted it never gets executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle that event to some element or just call it in your controller.

```
var app = angular.module('movieApp', []);
app.controller('movieController',
    function movieController($scope, $http) {
        // define default value
        $scope.results = [];

        $scope.fetchReviews = function() {
            var api = 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/all.jsonp?&offset=20&order=by-opening-date&api-key=XXX MY KEY XXX&responce-format=.jsonp&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'; 
            $http.jsonp(api).success(function(data){
                $scope.results = data.results;
            });
        }

        // call that event
        $scope.fetchReviews();
});
```

Try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('movieController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.fetchReviews = function() {
        var api = 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/movies/v2/reviews/all.jsonp?&offset=20&order=by-opening-date&api-key=XXX MY KEY XXX&responce-format=.jsonp&callback=JSON_CALLBACK'; 
        $http.jsonp(api).success(function(data){
            $scope.results = data.results;
        });
    }
    $scope.fetchReviews();
});
```

check like this